# /accounts/test-users giving OAuthException

Tags: facebook, unit-testing, testing, facebook-graph-api, integration-testing

For some reason, I'm suddenly having trouble accessing my test users via the graph.

GETting this ...

https://graph.facebook.com/229607217115781/accounts/test-users&access_token=MYAPPACCESSTOKENHERE

Gives me:

{
  "error": {
    "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 104
  }
}

MYAPPACCESSTOKEN has been generated by calling
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=MYAPPID&client_secret=SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials

and it returns the token just fine.

Looking at my git history, I'm pretty sure that this has worked before, making me suspect it's some breaking change I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is marked as a 'Desktop' app; you can't use the App Access Token for app administration via the API because it's assumed that you've distributed the app access token with the application binary and thus it can't be trusted as any of your users can decompile the app and get the app secret that way.

You can still use the Administration interface on developers.facebook.com for managing test users, or you can set your app back to 'Web' mode and the app secret will be usable for that call again